# .update in Firestore, is replacing all data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've already reviewed the documentation found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data.

I have a profile page where individuals can update specific content, i.e. phone number.

Even though I am using `update` all content in the profile page is replaced when the submit button is clicked. I only want data that is different than what is in firebase to be updated. How do I do this?

```
    const profileData = {
      optInTexts: this.form.optInTexts,
      optInWhatsappMessages: this.form.optInWhatsappMessages,
      subscribeToMailingList: this.form.subscribeToMailingList,
      phoneWhatsapp: e164Whatsapp,
      phone: e164,
      workerSkills: this.form.workerSkills
    };

    const profileRef = await db.collection('users')
      .where("uid", "==", this.userId)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          db
            .collection("users")
            .doc(doc.id)
            .update({...profileData});
        });
      });
```

Comment: Don't query, instead, `.get` or `.update` the `.doc(uid)` directly (don't use `.where` bcs you already know where, the doc named `uid`. Also, have you tried to console.dir out the profileData object? Is the data there?

Comment: @RonRoyston, yes the `profileData` is there. I removed console log from the code snippet to keep things clean. Data is there and it doesn't re-create the object in Firestore, which is good. But now I need to selectively replace data.

Comment: `.update` is how to do it. like I said, you don't need to do `.where` since you know the specific document you need to 1) `get` to populate the form then 2) to `.update`

Comment: @RonRoyston, removing `.where` doesn't solve the issue. With it gone it still works. So I'll leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) method along with `{ merge: true }`, like so:

```
ref.set({
  ...profileData
}, { merge: true });
```